# Use of unassigned local variable "strb" StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

So I am trying to learn how to use the `StringBuilder` Class. I read up about it and it seems amazing compared to `string` !

I am trying to create the `StringBuilder` in the other button but it keeps throwing me the error:

> ; expected" and Use of unassigned local variable "strb"

on line 42 & 43.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication15
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
        {
            string nrmlString = "C#";
            nrmlString += " This";
            nrmlString += " is";
            nrmlString += " a";
            nrmlString += " Test";
            nrmlString += " Thisss";

            MessageBox.Show(nrmlString);                    
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder strb new StringBuilder("something");
            strb.Append("Something else");    
            MessageBox.Show(strb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Local variables aren't initialized. I have to manually initialize them, But how?

Comment: You missed `=` : `StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder("something");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@VargaDev,
Your error was a simple missing of the = in your code.

```
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder("something");
```

And it has already been answered. I just chimed in for a suggestion. When trying this type of codes, using VS and creating a form is cumbersome. Have a check at the wonderful (and free) utility LinqPad. You can use that as a code scratch pad. ie: For testing your code above, you would simply do this:

-Choose C# statements (or C# program) from the combo
-Type

```
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder("something");
strb.Append("Something else");
strb.ToString().Dump();
```

and hit F5. That is it! Dump() is on streoids. You can dump almost anything, it shows the result in a suitable way (a datagrid for example if it is a list like thing).

PS: I don't have any affiliation with the author of the utility (Joseph Albahari), just a lover of it. It is (and he is) worth to be appraised.

Comment: That sounds amazing! Would you be able to provide me a link or two where I could read upa bout this subject?

Comment: http://www.linqpad.net

http://www.albahari.com

Answer (score 3):

You missed one `=` in your `button2_Click`:

```
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder("something");
strb.Append("Something else");
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir! This happends to me alot when I look to close for the error! I will try to work on this flaw of mine. I'l accept the answer as soona s it lets me which should be in about 10 minutes.